# Chart js: How to select a rectangular area with the mouse

Tags: javascript, chart.js

A requirement is to have the users select a rectangular area of the chart with the mouse. How do I accomplish this? Do I need some javascript library that extends chart js?

When I select an area with the mouse, a dragging operation starts instead of selecting anything.

Comment: What do you expect to happen after you selected an area? If you want to zoom in on the selected area, you may use [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/)

Comment: Zooming is in fact what I need to do after an area is selected but the client doesn't want to use the mouse wheel for this. So you need to select an area with the mouse, then get the data for that area from the API and refresh the chart.

Comment: Resolved. I was able to do the selection using the drag feature of Chart js.

Comment: Nice, maybe you could post an answer to [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with details and code; I'd be interested, it seemed very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do the selection using the drag feature of Chart js. This is what I did:

```
plugins: {
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'xy',
        zoom: {
            wheel: {
                enabled: true
            },
            pinch: {
                enabled: true
            },
            drag: {
                enabled: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                modifierKey: 'ctrl'
            },
        },
        pan:{
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'xy'
        }
    }
```